# The Chart.JS Won't Show In The Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I don't know what went wrong, there is no such an error notif, but the data in the chart won't show in the browser. I'm trying to make a simple **chart data using react-chartjs-2**.

[image: the problem]

**Here is my code: Chart.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            chartData: {
                labels: ['Boston', 'Worcester', 
                'Springfield', 'Lowell', 
                'Cambridge', 'New Bedford'],
                datasets:[
                    {
                        label: 'Population',
                        data: [
                            617594,
                            181045,
                            153060,
                            106519,
                            105162,
                            95072
                        ],
                        backgroundColor:[
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)',
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
                          ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
   
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="chart">
                <Bar
                    data={this.state.chartData}
                    options={{
                        maintainAspectRatio: false
                    }}
                />                    
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Chart;
```

**And here my App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Chart from './components/Chart';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Chart />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I already install the react-chartjs-2, and seems it still doesnt work here.

Comment: You have blocked some js errors in chrome console filter, remove that, that may give you some clue about the error.

Comment: No, i don't block the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `chart.js` too, also you need to register them like this:

```
import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from "chart.js";
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";

ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);

<Doughnut data={...} />
```

[Check the docs here](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/)